# How to display current country and city in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am looking for JavaScript which gives me the ability to display City and Country on my application.

Like in image below:

[image: example]

I tried many different solutions, through geolocation, and etc., Doesn't display anything, somebody know how to find right working script, because even here I found some solutions, but doesn't display anything!

One of the examples below! Will appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.JavaScript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
var city = geoip_city();
var country = geoip_country_name();
</script>
</head>
<body>
You are from <script>document.write(city)</script>, <script>document.write(country)</script>.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use API for this.

Check this, see if it helps you

http://www.jquery4u.com/api-calls/geolocation-jquery-api-geoplugin/